# Ansible loop giving warning found a duplicate dict key (when). Using last defined value only

Tags: ansible, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to iterate over an array and assign the value to variables `hooks_enabled`, `workflow_artifact_id`, `workflow_version`, one by one in every iteration and perform a specific task (currently `debug`, later change to `Helm install` command).
Code:

```yaml
---
- name: Executing Ansible Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: someuser
  pre_tasks:
    - include_vars: global_vars.yaml
    - name: Print some debug information 
      set_fact: 
        all_vars: |
          Content of vars
          --------------------------------
          {{ vars | to_nice_json }}

  tasks:
    - name: Iterate over an array
      set_fact:
        hooks_enabled: '{{ array_item1_hooks_enabled }}'
        workflow_artifact_id: '{{ array_item1_workflow_artifact_id }}'
        workflow_version: '{{ array_item1_workflow_version }}'
      when: "item == 'array_item1'"
      set_fact:
        hooks_enabled: '{{ array_item2_hooks_enabled }}'
        workflow_artifact_id: '{{ array_item2_workflow_artifact_id }}'
        workflow_version: '{{ array_item2_workflow_version }}'
      when: "item == 'array_item2'"
      with_items: "{{ array}}"
    # Change debug with helm install command
    - debug:
        msg: " id= '{{ workflow_artifact_id }}'"
```

The issue I am facing is, only the last `when` is considered and others are skipped

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
[WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from /c/ansible-test/second.yaml, line 16, column 7, found a duplicate dict key (set_fact). Using last defined value only.
[WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from /c/ansible-test/second.yaml, line 16, column 7, found a duplicate dict key (when). Using last defined value only.

PLAY [Executing Ansible Playbook] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [include_vars] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print some debug information] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Iterate over an array] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=array_item1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=array_item2)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=array_item3)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=array_item4)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=array_item5)

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": " id= 'algorithm-Workflow'"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

How do I modify the block to enable all the when statement execute and later use `helm install` command to take the variables one by one.

Comment: You have 1 task using `set_fact` twice. Separate the second `set_fact` task with `-`.

Comment: @seshadri_c if I add - , then I get error
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'item == 'array_item1'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item == 'array_item1'): 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/c/ansible-test/second.yaml': line 16, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Iterate over an array\n      ^ here\n"}

Comment: @seshadri_c Code:
```
  -   name: Iterate over an array
      set_fact:
        hooks_enabled: '{{ array_item1_hooks_enabled }}'
        workflow_artifact_id: '{{ array_item1_workflow_artifact_id }}'
        workflow_version: '{{ array_item1_workflow_version }}'
      when: "item == 'array_item1'"
  -   set_fact:
        hooks_enabled: '{{ array_item2_hooks_enabled }}'
        workflow_artifact_id: '{{ array_item2_workflow_artifact_id }}'
        workflow_version: '{{ array_item2_workflow_version }}'
      when: "item == 'array_item2'"
      with_items: "{{ array}}"
```

Comment: I want to use that loop for this complete task.
Also this is just an example, I will have to add more - set_facts statements for every array item.

Comment: Put all the `set_facts` task in a separate file and `include_tasks` it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a dynamic variable construction using the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html).

Something along the lines of:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    hooks_enabled: "{{ lookup('vars', item ~ '_hooks_enabled') }}"
    workflow_artifact_id: "{{ lookup('vars', item ~ '_workflow_artifact_id') }}"
    workflow_version: "{{ lookup('vars', item ~ '_workflow_version') }}"
  when: "item in ['array_item1', 'array_item2']"
  with_items: "{{ array }}"
```